# Look at below. I don't understand the program

Tags: python-2.7

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

How can I get output like below

```
The script is called: script.py
Your first variable is: first
Your second variable is: 2nd
Your third variable is: 3rd
```

I got the program from http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex13.html

Comment: The explanation is halfway down the page you linked http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex13.html#what-you-should-see

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the script `script.py`, then run it from the command line like so:

```
python script.py first 2nd 3rd
```